# How to write a conditional collect in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Imagine I have this structure:

```
class Foo {
   String bar
}
```

Now imagine I have several instance of `Foo` whose `bar` value is `baz_1`, `baz_2`, and `zab_3`.

I want to write a collect statement that only collects the `bar` values which contain the text `baz`. I cannot get it to work, but it would look something like this:

```
def barsOfAllFoos = Foo.getAll().bar
assert barsOfAllFoos == [ 'baz_1', 'baz_2', 'zab_3' ]
def barsWithBaz = barsOfAllFoos.collect{ if( it.contains( "baz" ) { it } ) } // What is the correct syntax for this?
assert barsWithBaz == [ 'baz_1', 'baz_2' ]
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need [`findAll`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
barsOfAllFoos.findAll { it.contains 'baz' }
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. So when I use `collect` does that require some transformed version of every element in the list I'm "collecting" from to be returned?

Comment: collect is used to transform a collection, find will filter it :-)

Comment: And if you want to filter and transform in one step, there's `collectMany`.

Comment: @ataylor thanks. `collectMany` was exactly what i was searching for

Comment: I think @Justin_Piper had the best answer here.  using collectMany is clunky compared to `findResults`

Answer (score 54):

If you want to both filter and transform there's lots of ways to do this. After 1.8.1 I'd go with `#findResults` and a closure that returns null for the elements I want to skip.

```
def frob(final it) { "frobbed $it" }

final barsWithBaz = barsOfAllFoos.findResults {
    it.contains('baz')? frob(it) : null
}
```

In earlier versions you can use `#findAll` and `#collect`

```
final barsWithBaz = barsOfAllFoos
                  . findAll { it.contains('baz') }
                  . collect { frob(it) }
```

Or `#sum`

```
final barsWithBaz = barsOfAllFoos.sum([]) {
    it.contains('baz')? [frob(it)] : []
}
```

Or `#inject`

```
final barsWithBaz = barsOfAllFoos.inject([]) {
    l, it -> it.contains('baz')? l << frob(it) : l
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `findResults` did not work for me... If you want to collect a transformed version of the values matching the condition (for instance a regex search of many lines) you can use `collect` followed by `find` or `findAll` as follows.

```
def html = """
    <p>this is some example data</p>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        form.action = 'http://www.example.com/'
        // ...
    </script>
"""

println("Getting url from html...")
// Extract the url needed to upload the form
def url = html.split("\n").collect{line->
    def m = line =~/.*form\.action = '(.+)'.*/
    if (m.matches()) {
        println "Match found!"
        return m[0][1]
    }
}.find()

println "url = '${url}'"
```

This returns the part of the line matching the given pattern.

```
Getting url from html...
Match found!
url = 'http://www.example.com/'
```